# Coproduct of Lie algebras

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, lie-algebras

Fix a commutative ring $k$ and look at the category of Lie algebras over $k$. How do coproducts in that category look like? Notice that what is usually called the "direct sum" of Lie algebras is not the coproduct. The underlying set of the coproduct $L \sqcup L'$ of two Lie algebras $L,L'$ will contain (arbitrarily?) nested Lie brackets such as $[[a,b],c]$ with $a,c \in L$, $b \in L'$. I wonder if there is any concise description, i.e. a sort of normal form, similar to the one which is available for the coproduct of groups.

Comment: Are you familiar with the special case of coproducts of copies of $k$? These are free Lie algebras.

Comment: At least I've seen the construction of free Lie algebras in a lecture back in 2007. IIRC it was just the general method of constructing free algebraic structures, without normal forms. I hope that the coproduct of two Lie algebras is simpler than the coproduct of finitely many Lie algebras. Perhaps this is a bit naive.

Comment: Well, already the coproduct of two copies of $k$ is not trivial to describe explicitly. You can give an explicit basis of free Lie algebras using Lyndon words (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Lie_algebra#Lyndon_basis) and I expect that the case of coproducts looks similar.

Comment: @Qiaochu: This sounds reasonable.

Comment: The category of Lie algebras is equivalent to the category of locally conilpotent Hopf algebras (Milnor--Moore theorem, 7.2.19 in [this book](http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~fresse/OperadHomotopyBook/HopfAlgebras.pdf)). It might be easier to understand the coproduct of the Hopf algebras? Then $\mathfrak{g} \sqcup \mathfrak{h} \cong \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{U}\mathfrak{g} \sqcup \mathbb{U}\mathfrak{h})$. [This paper describes the coproduct of Hopf algebras](http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2613v3), but I haven't read it in detail. Not sure if that helps.